# Extract numbers out of a textbox

Tags: c#, textbox, picturebox

I have to make a program for school, a D-FlipFlop. To enter D and the e/clock I want to use 2 textboxes. (I also had to make a program with 3 ports that contain AND, NAND, OR, NOR, XOR ports, but that already works).

Input for `D` can be: `000001111100000111111100000011`

Input for `E` can be: `000111000111000111000111000111`

The value from `textbox1` must go to a `picturebox`. So that with `0` and `1` you can draw a line and make the flipflop visual. The value from `textbox2` needs to go to `picturebox2`.

Comment: myTextbox.Text? I need to see some code in your question!

Comment: Sounds like you better start writing some code... if this is a school assignment it would not do you any good to have us code it for you without you understanding basic coding to begin with.. what if the instructor asked you how you came about your answer / solution..? then you would look like a deer in headlights..!

Comment: You have described a project, but have not asked a question, do you have problems with reading text from the textbox, drawing it in the picturebox, draw the lines, calculate the result, drawing the result.  Which part troubles you?

Comment: the only thing i have now is textBox1_KeyPress. e.Handled = !("\b01".Contains(e.KeyChar)); so that there are only 0 en 1 in the textbox. so the value of the textbox contains a row of 0 and 1. i want to put every single number in a new int. so that i can use the 0 or 1 to tell the picturebox1 how to draw a line. But i think id better stop now and start fresh in the morning haha

Comment: @user1786774 Based on what I've understood from your question, you'd like to read an `Image` from `bytes[]`. Then, link the `Image` to a `PictureBox`. Isn't it? Please correct me if I'm wrong. Have a great day :)

Comment: yes i think. i want those bytes / the row of 0 and 1 translated to a image. so that the row of 0 and 1 is visable as an image.

Comment: @user1786774 Great, I was able to do this. I'll post my answer in a second :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible. You'll actually need to convert `000001111100000111111100000011` or `000111000111000111000111000111` which will be treated as `string` to a byte array `byte[]`. To do this, we'll use `Convert.ToByte(object value, IFormatProvider provider)`

```
string input = "BINARY GOES HERE";
int numOfBytes = input.Length / 8; //Get binary length and divide it by 8
byte[] bytes = new byte[numOfBytes]; //Limit the array
for (int i = 0; i < numOfBytes; ++i)
{
     bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(input.Substring(8 * i, 8), 2); //Get every EIGHT numbers and convert to a specific byte index. This is how binary is converted :)
}
```

This will declare a new string `input` and then encode it to a byte array (`byte[]`). We'll actually need this as a `byte[]` to be able to use it as a `Stream` and then insert it into our `PictureBox`. To do this, we'll use `MemoryStream`

```
MemoryStream FromBytes = new MemoryStream(bytes); //Create a new stream with a buffer (bytes)
```

Finally, we can simply use this stream to create our `Image` file and set the file to our `PictureBox`

```
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(FromBytes); //Set the image of pictureBox1 from our stream
```

**Example**

```
private Image Decode(string binary)
{
    string input = binary;
    int numOfBytes = input.Length / 8;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[numOfBytes];
    for (int i = 0; i < numOfBytes; ++i)
    {
        bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(input.Substring(8 * i, 8), 2);
    }
    MemoryStream FromBinary = new MemoryStream(bytes);
    return Image.FromStream(FromBinary);
}
```

By using this, you can whenever call, for example `Decode(000001111100000111111100000011)` and it will convert it to an image for you. Then, you may use this code to set the `Image` property of a `PictureBox`

```
pictureBox1.Image = Decode("000001111100000111111100000011");
```

**IMPORTANT NOTICE:** You may receive `ArgumentException was unhandled: Parameter is not valid.` this might happen due to an invalid Binary code.

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)